# SQL - Rolling avg over truncated date

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, amazon-redshift

I want to do a rolling mean of a calculated field on a week basis out of data whose precision is at the second. This is why I first truncate the date to the week.

So my provisional query is

```
SELECT week, AVG(my_value) OVER(ORDER BY week ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS avg_my_value 
FROM
    (SELECT id, 
           DATE_TRUNC('week', created_at) AS week,
           my_value
    FROM my_table
    ORDER BY week ASC
    ) 
GROUP BY week
```

The problem I have is that the AVG works but it's done separately for all rows which have got the same week! I think this is because there must be some sort of inner grouping added but the problem I have is to conceive it for the case of an average.

If that counts, I am looking for a solution working for Redshift, or PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a cumulative average, then:

```
SELECT week,
       AVG(AVG(my_value)) OVER (ORDER BY week ASC) AS avg_my_value 
FROM (SELECT id,  DATE_TRUNC('week', created_at) AS week, my_value
      FROM my_table
     ) t
GROUP BY week;
```

Notes:

- The `ORDER BY` in the subquery is superfluous.
- Note the nesting of the aggregation functions.

Comment: You're missing the frame clause ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW in the window function. Also, why do I need to do an average of an average?

Comment: @martin . . . Postgres (and almost all other databases) do not require that clause.  Amazon Redshift might still require the windowing clause with `order by`.

Comment: It does indeed. How about the average of the average? It's not the same thing of doing one single average as what this is doing is first averaging all values for the same week and then computing the rolling average till that week.

Comment: @martin . . . You can use very similar logic to take the sum of the values divided by the sum of the counts.  That would be the overall average rather than the average of the weekly averages.

Comment: Yea, done that indeed! Was aiming for a one solution with pure AVG function though. Is it not possible at all?